# Foxit icon picture is missing from Dashboard

Tags: icons, foxitreader

I installed Foxit Reader from the Foxi web page. Hear is the link [of the Foxi reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/). I have a problem, the icon in ubuntu dashboard is there but the picture is missing. When I first installed the picture was there, but suddenly the picture is gone. Please anyone help me. Hear is a picture of the dashboard.

[image]

Answer (score 23):

I too faced a similar problem when installing FoxitReader in Ubuntu 12.04. I dug out a solution by going through the .desktop launcher file.

There will probably be 2 FoxitReader.desktop files on your system.

1. The global one at `/usr/share/applications/FoxitReader.desktop`, and
2. The local one at `~/.local/share/applications/FoxitReader.desktop` which overrides the global one

In my case the local file had its `Icon` pointing to a non-existent png file `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/FoxitReader.png`. I just copied the icon file from the `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps` directory to the pointed to location with

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps
cp /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/FoxitReader.png ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps`
```

and Voila! The icon started showing again.

**EDIT:**

I just checked and simply setting `Icon=FoxitReader` as done in the global .desktop file is enough

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same problem but I can't find the global.desktop file you were talking about.

Comment: Hey, just try running `sudo find / -name 'FoxitReader.desktop'` to locate the file on your system. If you can't find it, google for a FoxitReader.desktop file (I found one at https://gist.github.com/hakan648/4aca7b6709fd2fd09b3f) or just look at any other .desktop file on your system to see the format the file is written and write one yourself.

Comment: Hey, I'll have a look and see if that works. Thanks :)

Comment: For me, I just changed the `default-application-icon` at the `Icon` entry in the .desktop file (local to profile) to `FoxitReader` and it worked (16.04)

Comment: For me setting `Icon=FoxitReader` does not work, I had to specify the full path. I am on Linux Mint, though.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out thanks to [krypto07's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/744051/527764)

1. Open `FoxitReader.desktop` file by entering `sudo -H gedit ~/.local/share/applications/FoxitReader.desktop` in terminal (i am using gedit - you might use any text editor)
2. Here, you will find `Icon=/home/<pc name>/.local/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/FoxitReader.png`
3. Give the exact path of the icon/image which you want to display and save it.

Note: you can find icon for foxitreader in the folder named "image" which can be found in the installation folder of it or you can download it or you can display any image which you want to display, you just have to give correct full path of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can just remove the settings under `~/.local/share/applications/` directory:

1. Check if you have `/user/share/applications/FoxitReader.desktop`
2. Open it and confirm you have: `Icon=FoxitReader`
3. `cd ~/.local/share/applications/` and `mv FoxitReader.desktop FoxitReader.backup`
4. Restart your computer and search in top left corner "Search your computer" for "foxit", now you should see the icon, just drag it to your launcher bar.
5. Now you are good to remove `FoxitReader.backup` you created in step

Comment: you probably meant '/usr/share/applications/...'

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue.

Reason: unable to locate png image file.

As shown in above image, search in Dashboard looks for png image at `.local/share/icons/hicolor/...` directory. But it is able to locate FoxitReader.png image there.

Step followed by to resolve this issue:

1. Searched for FoxitReader.png using find command. "FoxitReader.png" was shown in `/usr/share/local/icons/hicolor/...`.
   Search output:
   [image]
2. Simply copied all the png image in `/usr/share/local/icons/hicolor/...` to `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/...`

This immediately shows icons on dashboard search. No reboot required.